# parameters() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' even after instantinating model

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to one time run my model and see if it's working. I've searched the error and suggested answers was to instantiate the model once. I already did that.  However, even after instantiating the model. it gives an error once requesting access to model parametes. What's the problem?

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, TensorDataset

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython import display
display.set_matplotlib_formats('svg')



data  = np.array([[1,1]])
label = np.array([2])

for i in range(-50,51,1):
  data = np.append(data, [[i,i]], axis=0)
  label = np.append(label, [i+i])




# conver to tensor

T_data  = torch.tensor(data).float()
T_label = torch.tensor(label).long()



# split data

train_data, test_data, train_label, test_label = train_test_split(T_data, T_label, test_size= .2)

# convert into Pytorch dataset

train_data = TensorDataset(train_data, train_label)
test_data  = TensorDataset(test_data, test_label)

# translate into dataloader

batchsize = 32

train_loader = DataLoader(train_data, batch_size= batchsize, shuffle =True, drop_last=True)
test_loader  = DataLoader(test_data, batch_size=test_data.tensors[0].shape[0])


  class AddNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()

      self.input = nn.Linear(2,16)

      ## hidden layer
      self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16,32)
      self.fc2 = nn.Linear(32,1)

      #output layer
      self.output = nn.Linear(1,1)

      # forward pass

      def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.input(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        return self.output(x)


net =AddNN()
lossfun = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(AddNN.parameters(), lr = .05)
```

It returns `TypeError: parameters() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`
What it means to have missing a required positional argument here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After model instantiation, you should use that model object instead of the model class inside `Adam` and with `.parameters()`

```
net = AddNN()
lossfun = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr = .05)
```